# Using 'Decimal' numbers with scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have numbers too large to use with Python's inbuilt types and as such am using the decimal library. I want to use `scipy.optimise.brentq` with a function that operates on 'decimals' but when the function returns decimal it obviously cannot be used with the optimisation function's float based internals. How can I get around this: **How can I use scipy optimisation techniques with the Decimal class for big numbers?**

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Scipy heavily relies on numerical algorithms that only deal with true numerical data types, and can't deal with the decimal class.

As a general rule of thumb: If your problem is well-defined and well-conditioned (that's something that numerical mathematicians define), you can just scale it so that it fits into normal python `float`s, and then you can apply scipy functionality to it.

If your problem, however, involves very small numbers as well as numbers that can't fit into `float`, there's little you can numerically do about that problem usually: It's hard to find a good solution.

If, however, your function only returns values that **would** fit into float, then you could just use

```
lambda x: float(your_function(x))
```

instead of `your_function` in `brentq`.

Comment: It's just started working, it seems the issue wasn't in scipy. Is Scipy internally converting it to a float or is it working with the decimal?

Comment: scipy will never use decimal internally! the first sentence of @Markus Müller explains it!